# how to search for all constructors in c++ code?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have to find out all the constructors in my code base (which is huge) , is there any easy way to do it (without opening each file , reading it and finding all classes)? Any language specific feature that I can use in my grep?

To find destructors it is easy , I can search for "~".
I can write some code to find "::" and match right and left words , if they are equal then I can print that line.
But if constructor is inside the class (with in H/HPP file), the above logic is missing.

Comment: what IDE you using ?

Comment: search for the word `class` then grab its name and look up the function after  `{` that has the same name?

Comment: the question is if you also should find existing constructors or just the user-defined ones. Whenever you declare structure r class, you create a constructor, unless you explicitly delete it..

Comment: Temporarily change the name of a class (not by refactoring) and compile. The compiler will raise errors at the  constructors and destructors.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're thinking of using grep, I'm assuming you want to do it programmaticly, and not in an IDE.
It also depend if you're parsing the header or the code, again I'm assuming you want to parse the header.

I did it using python:

```
inClass=False
className=""
motifClass=re.compile("class [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z1-9_]*)")#to get the class name
motifEndClass=re.compile("};")#Not sure that'll work for every file
motifConstructor=re.compile("~?"+className+"\(.*\)")
res=[]
#assuming you already got the file loaded
for line in lines:
    if not inClass:#we're searching to be in one
        temp=line.match(class)
        if temp:
            className=res.group(1)
            inClass=True
    else:
        temp=line.match(motifEndClass)
        if temp:#doesn't end at the end of the class, since multiple class can be in a file
            inClass=False
            continue
        temp=line.match(motifConstructor)
        if temp:
            res.append(line)#we're adding the line that matched
#do whatever you want with res here!
```

I didn't test it,I did it rather quickly, and tried to simplify an old piece of code, so numerous things are not supported, like nested classes.
From that, you can do a script looking for every header in a directory, and use the result how you like !

Comment: i can try this, but will it work for classes inside classes(sub classes)?

Comment: using what i posted, no, it doesn't handle them (sub classes==inner classes) but you can generalize it to handle them by adding a stack to keep track of how deep you are.

Answer (score 0):

Search all classes names and then find the function has same name like class name. And second option is that as we know that the constructor is always be public so search word public and find the constructor.

Comment: The `public` keyword might not appear , functions default to public in structs. Your first suggestion might work though.

Comment: Constructors are not always public.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the constructors is fairly simple (as other had said).... Finding all *calls* to constructors and destructors is non-trivial and so far has eluded me....